# ERROR 500 Bot Framework Microsoft

Tags: javascript, frameworks, bots, botframework

This is my screen when I get the error as soon as I try to connect to the bot
[image]

My code was working before but I had a problem with my MS account so I had to change account with new credentials and they aren't working anymore :/

I tried this also and it works :
[image]

if i get rid of credentials, and basically all the auth, the bot works perfectly.
However when I put the auth back it gives me this error :

`[16:22:24] -> POST Request to 'http://localhost:3978/api/messages' failed: [500] Internal Server Error`

which isn't really helpful

Thanks for your answers! :)

Comment: Try going to dev.botfrmework.com and deleting and adding your bot again.

Comment: But... you are trying to connect to bot in localhost using the auth credentials? That won't work unless you use ngrok

Comment: I am using ngrok

Comment: You can actually see ngrok running in the logs of the emulator

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty sure it also worked for me before. However, it doen't actually matter as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44687339/5118785).

- The purpose of localhost is just to test your bot.
- You could test your credentials by deploying your bot and registering it in the [development portal](http://dev.botframework.com).

I encountered the same problem, but my credentials were just fine when I tested them in the portal. So, probably yours are too.

Comment: The thing I am wondering is that it was working last week for a bit more than a month (and I did not do any update(s))

Comment: I edited my answer; According to the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/debug-bots-emulator) it should still be supported. As I said, though, I had the same "problem", but my credentials were just fine. So, I would recommend that you test your credentials in the portal and locally just don't use them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I don't really get what the problem is but I'll follow your advice :)